# Formula to add a number to the cell and change that value if it is greater than certain number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Column A I have numbers from 1 to 30 and in Column B I want to add 10 to the number in column A i.e.

if A1 is `1` I want `11` in B1 and in C1 I want `21` and
if A2 is `2` I want `12` in B2 and in C2 I want `22`.

I don't want the numbers in columns B and C to exceed the maximum limit of numbers I have in Column A, in this case that is `30`.

I need a formula to achieve this so that none of the cells in column B and C has the number exceeding `30` and if the addition exceeds that I want 30 to be subtracted from it. I tried this with IF but it didn't help as I don't know how to manipulate the current cell after adding the number.

Screenshot of expected results:
[image: Screenshot of expected results]

I want the number in B Column to be addition of `10` to the number in A Column and it should not exceed maximum number.

Comment: Can you post the formula you have tried?

Comment: =IF(A1>=30,A1-30+10,A1+10), but i dont know how to do this after adding number, this is in B1

Comment: Post an example that shows the challenge you're facing. Screenshot, sample file, use a file sharing service, but please use an ad-free one, like Dropbox or Onedrive.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Please edit your question to include a) the formula, b) an example that *doesn't* work as intended.

Comment: In your if formula instead of checking A1>=30 just do A1>20...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Maybe*, in B1:

```
=A1+10-30*(A1+10>30)
```

and in C1, both copied down to suit:

```
=B1+10-30*(B1+10>30)
```

Considering B1, the above can be simplified slightly by rendering `(A1+10>30)` down to `(A1>20)`.

`A1+10` is the basic requirement.

The condition is that where `A1+10` exceeds `30`, a deduction of 30 should be applied. This can be restated as "where A1 exceeds 20".

`(A1>20)` returns either TRUE (when A1 is more than 20) and FALSE (otherwise).

What may not have been appreciated by all is that when used as a multiplier, Excel treats TRUE as `1` and FALSE as `0`.

So when A1 is less than or equal to `20`, nothing is deducted from to A1+10. `30*(A1>20)` becomes `30*FALSE` (effectively `30*0`), which is `0`. However, when A1 is more than 20 `30*(A1>20)` becomes `30*TRUE` (effectively `30*1`), which is `30`.

Comment: Wow, awesome this is what i was after, thanks pnuts..  but can you please explain what it is ?

Comment: ha ha not really just a simple game in our office

Comment: Then working out what is happening is good for you and your colleagues... Neat @pnuts

Comment: well, security guards dont discuss excel :D

Comment: Thanks pnuts for this

Answer (score 0):

The formula for B1 is:

```
=IF(A1+10>MAX($A$1:$A$30),A1+10-MAX($A$1:$A$30),A1+10)
```

(For C1 just do "Fill Right" from B1.)

Sometimes it's better to use several columns to get to the result:

First I created in D1 `=A1+10`, then in E1 `=MAX($A$1:$A$30)`.

The `$` means that the column or row number does not change when you fill down, so A1 stays fixed to A1 in every cell.

In F1 I created an [IF](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) formula: `=IF(D1>$E$1,D1-$E$1,D1)` which means "**IF** D1 exceeds the highest value in A1 to A30 **THEN** subtract that highest value from D1 **ELSE** just display D1 (=A1+10)"

And if you substitute these values:

(E1): `=IF(D1>MAX($A$1:$A$30),D1-MAX($A$1:$A$30),D1)`
(D1): `=IF(A1+10>MAX($A$1:$A$30),A1+10-MAX($A$1:$A$30),A1+10)`

you get the result I mentioned in the first place.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't do politics. I just do computer science.